# Using Selenium to Scrape AliExpress Shipping prices - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape the shipping data from AliExpress for a particular store. However, the code stops at Andorra. Also, It prints Afghanistan twice and lists the shipping prices for it but the first country this particular store ships to is Argentina. I am trying to store that data to excel sheet but printing it to the console just to check if it's working. My question is why, is it printing Afghanistan twice(also incorrectly printing shipping price) and why is it stopping at Andorra.

List of countries in link below. It includes over 200 countries. It shouldn't stop at Andorra.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/un7fh6pl3hc3567/Countries.txt?dl=0

**result once I run the program:**

Afghanistan

```
07/25   US $7.37        AliExpress Standard Shipping        07/29   US $40.17       EMS Afghanistan
```

This Supplier/Shipping Company does not deliver to your selected Country/Region.

Aland Islands

This Supplier/Shipping Company does not deliver to your selected Country/Region.

Albania

This Supplier/Shipping Company does not deliver to your selected Country/Region.

Alderney

This Supplier/Shipping Company does not deliver to your selected Country/Region.

Algeria

This Supplier/Shipping Company does not deliver to your selected Country/Region.

American Samoa

This Supplier/Shipping Company does not deliver to your selected Country/Region.

Andorra

This Supplier/Shipping Company does not deliver to your selected Country/Region.

See my code bellow :

```
def login(self):

    fail = True
    while fail:
        try:
            # Go to AliExpress Store.
            self.driver.get("https://www.aliexpress.com/store/all-wholesale-products/5795287.html?spm=a2g0o.detail.1000061.2.266e75e9QrlB4U")
            time.sleep(3.5)
            # Change location to USA, some stores don't ship worldwide so no products will be displayed.
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'currency') and contains(text(),'USD')]").click()
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav-global']/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/a[1]").click()
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'shipping-text') and contains(text(),'United States')]").click()
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='nav-global']/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/button").click()
            time.sleep(1.5)
            # Click first image
            self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("picCore.lazy-load").click()
            time.sleep(2.5)
            self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("next-dialog-close").click()
            time.sleep(4)
            # locate shipping URL
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[10]/span[1]").click()
            time.sleep(1)
            # Exit while loop
            fail = False

        except Exception:
            pass

    try:
        # List of countries (used by AliExpress) stored in a text file.
        # Create a list and store all the countries in a variable called "countries".
        with open('Countries.txt', 'r') as f:
            countries = [line.strip() for line in f]

        # Loop through the countries and get shipping prices.
        for country in countries:
            # Click dropdown arrow to access the countries and use variable "countries" to located each country.
            self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("next-select-arrow").click()
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'country-name') and contains(text(),'"+country+"')]").click()
            print(country)
            try:
                # If supplier don't ship to this country locate and print.
                # "This Supplier/Shipping Company does not deliver to your selected Country/Region."
                elements = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("next-message-content")
                print(elements.text)

            except Exception:

                try:
                    # If supplier does ship to this country locate and print cost, tracking and carrier.
                    elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('table-td')
                    for e in elements:
                        print(e.text + "\t", end='')

                except Exception:
                    print("Fail!!")

            time.sleep(2.5)

    except Exception:
        pass
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

I think your code was not working because the line

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'country-name') and contains(text(),'"+country+"')]").click()
```

was always throwing an exception. The reason? You're asking your code to click on something he can't see.

So I did this:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ae-search-select-1"]').send_keys(country)
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[12]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/div/ul/li').click()
```

You just need to change the old line by the new ones.

What does it do?
It types the name of the country in the search bar and clicks on the result.

--- EDIT ---

```
try:
   with open('Countries.txt', 'r') as f:
      countries = [line.strip() for line in f]
   for country in countries:
       print(country)
       self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("next-select-arrow").click()
       self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ae-search-select-1"]').send_keys(country)

       self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("next-menu-item")[-1].click()

       time.sleep(1)

          try:
              elements = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("next-message-content")
              print(elements.text)

          except Exception:

               try:
                   elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_class_name('table-tr')
                   for i in range(len(elements)):
                      print(elements[i].text.replace("\n",'\t'))
                except Exception:
                    print("Fail!!")

          elements = ""

 except Exception:
    pass
```

So this is the new code, it matches the price with the country

Comment: Thank you, That worked perfectly, it's going through the countries. I just need to figure out why it's mismatching the shipping and the countries.

Comment: how to run this. i want to scrape shipping cost table

Comment: @TipVisor You need to create a Python script. See [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage) how to use selenium with Python. Let me know if you have any difficulties.